# I want to implement RAID 1 for my two hard disks

Tags: raid-1

My system configuration is:

- Intel Core 2 Duo 2.2 Ghz with FSB 800MHZ and 2 MB L2 Cache
- Intel D945 GCNL Motherboard, which features 4 SATA and 1 IDE
- Mileinium RAID card, with 4 SATA and 1 IDE
- 2 * 500GB Samsung hard disks, 1 * 500GB Seagate hard disk

I am using Windows XP.

#### Question

One of the Samsung hard disks is full, and 1 Samsung and the Seagate are empty.

I want to implement RAID 1. I have tried with 2 hard disks connected to RAID adapater, and one to the motherboard. But my system would hang and did not displaying the Intel logo of the motherboard.

Please tell me the how to alter the configuration to do RAID 1 with 2 hard disks, and what the problem might be with my current arrangement?

Thanks

Comment: The answer depends on what you use for RAID. If it's hardware RAID, what is your RAID controller? If it's software RAID, what is your operating system?

Comment: it is hardware raid pci adapter which it supports raid 0 and raid 1

i am using windows xp the adapter which it may provides drivers to it

Answer (score 1):

It can be very hard to convert an existing hard drive to RAID, especially when using hardware RAID cards (as compared to software RAID where you sometimes get useful convert tools).

The best thing I can suggest, and it isn't that convenient, is to backup all your data then setup RAID and then reinstall your operating system and copy the data back.

If this is Windows, you may have luck either by performing a Sysprep generalise before shutting down for the last time then just copying all the data back to the RAID array, or at a last resort doing a repair install.

Raid is something that really needs to be thought about when initially setting up a machine, it is hard to migrate to at a later date as hard drives usually need to be prepared. I hope this does help you - if you need more info about sysprep, let me know and I will write it.

Comment: please tell me step by step instructions about the sysprep

Comment: For sysprep, simply go to Start > Run and type sysprep, then launch sysprep.exe - choose the shutdown and generalise button then ok. It will delete the association with your hardware and put Windows in a state where it is ready for cloning/moving to different hardware.

Next time you run, it will take a bit longer but install drivers needed. The only problem you may have is if the RAID array does not have built in Windows Drivers.

Comment: i am edited the question now please check it and give me solution

Answer (score 0):

Another suggestion is to use Acronis or similar program to make a Full Disk Image of your current hard drive, then set up your Raid 1, then use the Acronis boot CD to put the image you made onto the new raid 1 array, it is the fastest way to do what you want. This method be used if you are using software Raid.

1. I Purchase and Install Acronis on your current installation of Windows, make a Full disk Image (all partitions), save the image to an external usb hard drive.
2. Verify the Image using Acronis verify feature.
3. Use the Media Builder in Acronis to make the Acronis boot cd
4. Install your 2 hard drives and set up the raid array. (You never stated if you have on board raid or a controller card, so you will have to consult documentation for your hardware on how to do this)
5. Boot from the Acronis CD, recover the image you made and install it on the Raid 1 Array.

http://www.acronis.com/homecomputing/products/trueimage/

Comment: i am edited the question now please check it and give me solution